# Why do I need an inverse matrix to solve this problem?

Tags: matrices

I am teaching myself maths as a hobby and am doing matrices. A textbook asks the following.

> Find the inverse of the matrix $${\bf M} = \begin{pmatrix}
> -2 & 3 \\ -3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$$ Hence find the coordinates of the points whose images under the linear transformation with matrix $\bf M$ are the points $(0, -1)$, $(1, 1)$ and $(7, 10)$.

---

Now I can work out the images as follows:
In the first case:

$\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 3 \\
-3 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$\rightarrow -2a+3b=0, -3a+4b=-1 \\
\rightarrow a = 3, b = 2$

So the required image is $\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

I can work out the inverse $M^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & -3 \\
3 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ but why would I need it, and if I did need it how would I use it?

Comment: If you want to solve the matrix equation $Mx=v$ for $x$, then $x=M^{-1}v$, if $M$ is invertible. You will see, this is what the answers below explain.

Comment: Look at both the answers , they give you a general way to solve for an $n\times n$ system. When the number of equations increase, it is often easier to refer to an algorithmic procedure rather than solving arbitrarily by hand. The algorithmic procedure is precisely matrix inversion. Now there are procedures which you can follow to invert a matrix and it is not as easy as the $2\times 2$ case. Regardless it is doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use it as follows. Remember that
$$
MM^{-1} = M^{-1}M = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and so if you take that equation,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-2&3\\
-3&4
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a\\
b
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0\\
-1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
multiplying through by ${M^{-1}}$ will give you
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a\\
b
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
4&-3\\
3&-2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0\\
-1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
but now notice the left-hand side is just ${(a,b)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that: $M{a\choose b}= {a'\choose b'}$ iff $M^{-1}{a'\choose b'}= {a\choose b}$. So having computed the inverse matrix means you need not solve any more the system of eqns just carry out multiplication with inverse  matrix.

This is true for not only for $2\times2$ but also for $n\times n$ matrices.